# geolocation game event on marker approach

Tags: google-maps, react-native, mapbox

I need some information, I wan't to create a simple game with a geolocation API, I have looked at: Google Map API, MapBox.

I wan't to have the actual location of the user, he can see the map around him (like Pokemon GO), I can put a marker at 10 meters for example, when he approach the marker with his phone, I do an event, a popup appear, and he won a score is increased.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not write some code to achieve that?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hm no I just want to know on which API I can do that, becausee I don't found tutorial about that

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox SDK is versatile and allows for 'MapViews' inside of your own application's activity.
The have a great amount of information inside their docs. I'd say to start with their introduction apps and work your way up once you are familiar.

Ideas:

- You could customize the user location icon to be the player and use the proximity controls around the users fine location to reach goals/tasks.
- You could then have pins on the MapView that the user's location can interact with

Comment: I understand that this is opinionated, however the user is a new contributor and did not offer any code. I feel like this is what they were looking for.

Comment: Hmmm It's looks that what I want's, it's strange because I found any tutorial about location interaction

Comment: Thaere is no React Native component for MapBox

Comment: Unfortunate, I know they have great Java, Kotlin and Swift support